# Adding functionality to collection - subclass or create function?

Tags: c++, oop, subclassing

What is the convention for C++ when adding functionality (want to add public methods to class) to e.g. stl data collections? Should I subclass it or just create function taking object as an argument?
In Objective-C there are categories that can extend class's interface but I couldn't find a similar way to achieve it in c++.

Comment: Without knowing any context my first choice would be to just create a function.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to inherit from one of the standard containers. Have a look at the standard adaptors (eg `queue`) for another alternative. In general prefer composition to inheritance.